# Modify array in Angular does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting `$scope.persons` from a back end. I list it using `ng-repeat`.

Why will the array not be modified in my case when `$scope.openDeleteModal` is called?

The function is called but nothing happens to `$scope.persons.` Why?

```
application.controller('listPersonController', function ($scope, personService) {
   personService.getPersons()
  .then(function(persons) {
      $scope.persons = persons;
  });

  $scope.openDeleteModal = function (personId, firstname, lastname, index) {
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
    $scope.persons.splice();
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
  };
});
```

**Edit:**

OK I forget about splice. I use this instead

```
 $scope.openDeleteModal = function (personId, firstname, lastname, index) {
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
    $scope.persons = [];
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
  };
```

The first one logs 3. The second 0. But I do not see any changes on the scope(ng-repeat).

The HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="p in persons">
      <td>{{p.firstname}}</td>
      <td>{{p.lastname}}</td>
      <td><a href="#/register_person/{{p.id}}" class="tiny button radius" >Edit</a></td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" 
           ng-click="openDeleteModal(p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, $index)"
           class="tiny button alert radius">Delete</a>
      </td>
   </tr>  
</tbody>
```

The service:

```
personService.getPersons = function($scope){
   var promise = $http.get("rest/person").then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
   });
   return promise;
};
```

This is what `{{persons}}` just under the controller gives

[{"id":"5331c6f33004e1c8a26492a8","firstname":"Karl","lastname":"Svensson"},{"id":"5331dfdb3004e1c8a26492ad","firstname":"Jenny","lastname":"Bertilsson"},{"id":"5331ee4e3004e1c8a26492ae","firstname":"Bosse","lastname":"Gustavsson"}]

This does not change either when I modify the scope

**Edit** 
Trying to simplify stuff even more.

```
application.controller('listPersonController', function ($scope, personService) {

  var personsList =  [{"id":"5331dfdb3004e1c8a26492ad","firstname":"Johnny","lastname":"Bravo"}];

  $scope.persons = personsList;

  $scope.openDeleteModal = function (personId, firstname, lastname, index) {
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
    $scope.persons.length = 0;
    personsList.length = 0;
    console.log("click " + $scope.persons.length);
  };
});
```

**Edit:** The html is super simple now

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="listPersonController" >
    <p ng-repeat="p in persons">{{p.firstname}} <a href="#" class="tiny button alert radius" ng-click="openDeleteModal(p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, $index)" >Delete</a></p>
</div>
```

Even more simple. The value of `var` is 3 on my page and it does not get updated on click.

```
application.controller('listPersonController', function ($scope, personService) {

  $scope.var = "1";

  $scope.openDeleteModal = function () {
    $scope.var = "2";
  };

   $scope.var = "3";
});
```

**Edit:** Code works as expected when moved out from `ng-view`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Doesn't `splice` take 2 arguments? `.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: Well..that certainly is interesting - the view should most definitely update. Just for kicks tho - throw a `$scope.apply()` at the end of the method

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: Hmm...does the view ever update? After a few seconds or another Angular function?

Comment: could you post some of your HTML? as demoed here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/et9dxXR3cPUuthp7PxBN?p=preview
your approach should definitely work

Comment: @AbrahamP I added HTML and my Service method.

Comment: @tymeJV The view must updated because I get some rows in my table to start with.

Comment: I get that, but the method you run should trigger a digest cycle and apply to the view. Why that's not happening is the mystery

Comment: where in the html is your controller?
specifically is there another controller (or directive) between where your controller is applied to the html and where the ng-repeat takes place that uses the persons variable as well?

Comment: <div class="row" ng-controller="listPersonController" > is above the table. Its a very simple html.

Comment: The first two things I do when debugging angular is call `window.myScope = $scope;`  in the controller so I can access everything on the scope using chrome debugging tools, the second is display some `<h1>{ $id }</h1>` elements to see what the ID of the scope is in a given dom element then compare that to the ID of the scope that's attached to the `window.myScope.$id` property.

Comment: If this is inside a modal popup using angular-ui or something similar it's probably got a new child scope

Comment: @BenCr You are probably right but I am think I have eliminated that? Or trying to at least.

Comment: try changing the persons collection to be a property on an object. so $scope.persons = { list:[] } and bind to persons.list. I can't remember/don't really understand why this works with child scopes but it does.

Comment: Well you can easily confirm that you have by displaying the scopes IDs.

Comment: @BenCr Both scopes in my html above have the id of 005. Both the controller <div> and the <p> inside it

Comment: @BenCr Everytime I click delete the id of the scope is changed. The sounds incorrect But dont know the reason yet.

Comment: any chance you could put together a plunk/jsfiddle?

Comment: @AbrahamP I get it to work in plunker but when I move it into my app i t stops to work. Must debug more.

Comment: When i moved the code outside of my ng-view it started to work. How can a ng-view mess this up?

Comment: in your routes definition, is the ng-view tied to a controller? Does this controller do anything with persons?

Comment: It to the controller responsible for the top bar. I dont think it does anything with persons. At least it should not. I must dubbel check tonight.

Comment: Have you tried removing the  href="#" from the link? That might be making the page navigate to itself and causing the controller to be re-instantiated and therfore getting a new version

Comment: @BenCr Thats a very good point. I will come back to you about that.

Comment: @BenCr You solved my problem. It was the href="#" that was the problem. Go ahead and write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the href="#" from the link, it's probably causing the page to navigate to itself and causing the controller to be re-instantiated.

Comment: +1 U nailed it. The fact that, a controller getting refresh can alter the data structure is something we can miss out.

Comment: Wow, this was answered a long time ago. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: true, but I was new on angular was hunting for the unattended behavior. I had a button with `<a href="#" ...` then now its `<a href="javascript:void(0)"..`

Answer (score 1):

The `splice` method is not destructive when not passed any arguments.

What that means is that while it will return the spliced (empty) array, it will not overwrite the original array.

What that means for you is that if you want to call splice to clear out the whole array, you should call:

```
$scope.persons = $scope.persons.splice()
```

Though (without referencing the javascript source) it is my belief that

```
$scope.persons = []
```

will probably be faster.

Keep in mind that this will trigger a full digest cycle, triggering every `$watch` and bound attribute you've defined to be hit.

Comment: as demoed here http://plnkr.co/edit/et9dxXR3cPUuthp7PxBN?p=preview your approach should work. Any other controllers/HTML you could post?